# how can i make a progress indicator using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

> the result i want to achieve

[image]

how can i make a progress indicator using flutter?

I've tried using Flutter's built-in progress indicator but it's not what I want

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html

I've used it before, something went wrong. when I move pages (from home to settings) and back again to the home page. home page doesn't reload when I delete ProgressIndicator home page works fine

Comment: Can you include your sample code that will reproduce the same issue

Answer (score 0):

For tour purposes you can use [percent_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator) library

[image]

Comment: I've used it before, something went wrong. when I move pages (from home to settings) and back again to the home page. home page doesn't reload when I delete ProgressIndicator home page works fine @powerman23rus

Comment: I don't think that problem of library you have to check your code base

Answer (score 0):

```
              Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: const [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 45,
                    height: 45,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                        Color(0XFFA81E61),
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: Color(0XFFeab5b5),
                      value: 0.5,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text('1 / 2')
                ],
              )
```

Comment: i just got the answer i added valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>